# Проверка минимальной суммы ввода в форме input

Tags: php, javascript, html

Как реализовать эту проверку в html/php/js? 
Что бы при вводе числа меньше/равно 5-ти, выдавало ошибку как на скриншоте

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Какой-то непонятный салат. Ты хоть определись в клиентской части или серверной нужна эта проверка. И потом, если это какие-то хайпы для ввода или вывода денег, даже помогать не стану

Comment: Нужно что бы результат был как на скриншоте. Нет, не хайпы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
count = document.getElementById('count');
err = document.getElementsByClassName('err')[0];

count.onkeydown = function(event) {
  // count.value = count.value.replace(/[^0-9]/gim, '');
  // if(isNaN(count.value)) {count.value = current; count.selectionEnd = sel;}
  
  key = [48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 8, 37, 38, 39, 40, 16, 17];
  if(key.indexOf(event.keyCode) == -1) {return false;}
  
  this.onkeyup = function() {
    if(parseInt(count.value) < 5) {
      err.innerHTML = 'Мин. сумма 5';
      count.style = 'border-color: #FF7F66; color: #FF7F66;';
    } else {
      err.innerHTML = '';
      count.style = '';
    }
  }
  
  
}
```

```css
#count {
  padding: 12px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #C0C4C8;
  outline: none;
  transition: border .3s ease;
}

.err {
  color: #FF7F66;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: Segoe UI;
  margin-left: 4px;
}
```

```html
<label><input id='count' type="text"><div class='err'></div></label>
```

Comment: плохой вариант, попробуй ввести несколько цифр в середине, или перевести курсор стрелочкой

Comment: @Grundy, поправил, попробуй сейчас. Косяк всё равно остался, хоть ограничения для клавиш делай, но всё же лучше, чем было

Comment: последнее исправление плохое было, _"message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: current is not defined",_

Comment: @Grundy, в этом и косяк. Если начинаешь вводить не с цифр. Можно это пофиксить, но мне всё равно не нравится. Сейчас попробую что-то другое придумать

Comment: ну вообще, это сообщение из-за того что ты в последней редакции перенес определение current ниже чем оно используется, просто добавь `var current` и ошибка пропадет

Comment: @Grundy, может лучше ограничить клавиши? Тогда и прыгать ничего не будет

Comment: тогда надо keydown чтобы значения не успевали вводиться

Comment: @Grundy, Обновил. Нельзя только скопировать, вырезать или вставить, но здесь вроде это не нужно. Навигация полностью работает

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("form").submit(function() {
    var $form = $(this),
      $reqField = $(".required", $form),
      $errorText = $(".error-text", $form);

    if ($reqField.val() <= 5) {
      $reqField.addClass("error");
      $errorText.addClass("show");
    } else {
      $reqField.removeClass("error");
      $errorText.removeClass("show");
    }
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
}
.error {
  border: 1px solid #f00 !important;
  color: red;
}
input[type="text"] {
  color: #777;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
}
.error-text {
  display: none;
  color: red;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.error-text.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>

  <form action="#" method="post">
    <input type="text" class="required">
    <input type="submit">
    <div class="error-text">мин.сумма 5</div>
  </form>

  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Зачем нагружать сайт jquery, если можно обойтись без него, верно? Это подгрузка лишних ~100кб. К тому же можно сразу проверять без нажатия кнопки _отправить_. А ещё я ввожу буквы и ошибки нет

Comment: Конечно, лучше без  jquery, полностью согласен, голосую за ваш вариант.